# Path in src to reach a file in a different directory

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a folder called `projects` and in it I have a `game` folder and an `engine` folder.  I have my `engine.js` file inside the `engine` folder and I was wondering if I could access it with my `game.html` file  from the other folder like so

```
 <script type ="text/javascript" src ="\engine/engine.js"/>
```

Now, obviously the above doesn't work, but what I need to do is go back out of the `game` folder to the `project` folder and then into the `engine` folder.

**File tree: projects folder**

- projects

  - engine

    - engine.js
  - game

    - game.js

What is the proper format for `src` to provide users with a link to `engine.js`?

Comment: Not an answer, but a minor note: slashes on the internet are always forward slashes: /, not backslashes: \.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use a double-dot to go back:

`src="../engine/engine.js"`

Comment: Thanks! I thought this would be a simple answer but I didn't know what to search in order to find the info..

Comment: how can I go back to parent's parent folder?

Comment: @tim, just use another double dot: `src="../../engine/engine.js"`

Comment: thanks, I use it in vuejs. I found i can just write like `src="engine.js"`, and it worked, but thanks for your anwser

Answer (score 9):

That would be:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="../engine/engine.js"/>
```