# js and jquery validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

my html code is below

```
 <script src="js/validate.js"></script>
<label>FIRST NAME:</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" class="firstname" id="firstname" onKeyUp="firstname()" />
</td>
<td>
<label id="fn"></label>
```

and my js code is below

```
function firstname()
{
   var nname=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var l=nname.length > 3 ;
    if( !l)
    {
     producePrompt("firstname should not be less than 4 characters","fn","red");    
     return false;
    }
    else
    if(!nname.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/))
    {
        producePrompt("incorrect name","fn","red"); 
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
    producePrompt("correct","fn","green");  
     return true;
    }
}

function producePrompt(message,promptlocation,color)
{
    document.getElementById(promptlocation).innerHTML= message;
     document.getElementById(promptlocation).style.color= color;    
}
```

but my code is not showing the messages or does not validate it properly
the js is under a file named validate.js and html is in index.html
i tried both types (,) to include the js file but no validation is taking place

Comment: Can you put this in a js fiddle? Include also the validate.js

Comment: sorry i don't heard about js fiddle

Comment: HERE IS THE LINK http://jsfiddle.net/makk/6d6W4/

Comment: select no wrap in <head> in fiddle

Comment: @user3447573 check this http://jsfiddle.net/6d6W4/1/

Comment: @user3447573 works fine for me

Comment: Works in the fiddle if you do as @LOL suggests.

Comment: CAN I KNOW WHAT IS THE MISTAKE IN IT MR.LOL

Comment: @user3447573 no mistakes in your code, may be linking js script path incorectly. try to define function in script tag on html, then works perfectly.

Comment: PLEASE TRY THAT IN THE LINK GIVEN BY ME MR.LOL

Comment: @user3447573 what is the structure of files like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889354/linking-to-another-javascript-file-in-a-back-directory

Comment: i linked it properly ,but why it is not working in the above link given by me mr.lol

Comment: Check your console and find error and then show your error here.

Comment: IT DOES NOT SHOWS MR.SHASHANK

Answer (score 0):

try this , works fine for me (validation works) :

js :

```
function checkinput()

{

   var nname=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var l=nname.length > 3 ;
if(!l)
{
 console.log("firstname should not be less than 4 characters","fn","red");    
 return false;
}
else
if(!nname.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/))
{
    console.log("incorrect name","fn","red"); 
    return false;
}
else
{
   console.log("correct","fn","green");  
 return true;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<form>

<label>FIRST NAME:</label> <input type="text" class="firstname" id="firstname" onblur="checkinput()" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
   // all your html contents

   // load the scripts here
 <script src="js/validate.js"></script>
</body>
```

OR

```
 <body>
   // all your html contents

   <script>
     // javascript contents
   </script>

</body>
```